# Пунктуация при сравнительном обороте: "Укутался в одеяло(,) как в кокон, из которого торчала только черного цвета макушка"?

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

*– Свали с радара! Я спать хочу! – зевая, вскрикнул Дмитрий и укутался в одеяло(,) как в кокон, из которого торчала только черного цвета макушка.*

Вот можно спросить,  сравнительный оборот здесь входит в смысловой центр, или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свали с радара! Я спать хочу! – зевая, вскрикнул Дмитрий и укутался **в одеяло как в кОкон, из которого торчала только черного цвета макУшка.**

Интонационно-структурный анализ показывает, что запятая не нужна. В этом предложении придаточное определительное относится к слову ***кокон***, поэтому мы не можем его обособить, выделив паузами.

При другой структуре обособление возможно, например:

(1) ...и укутался **в одеЯло,  как в кОкон.**

(2) ....и укУтался, **как в кОкон,** в одеЯло,  из которого торчала только черного цвета макушка.

**Что говорят правила?**

Правила дают автору достаточную степень свободы, чтобы подобрать нужный вариант, хотя там говорится не об интонации, а об **выступлении на первый план определенного значения.** В нашем случае ***как в кокон*** является обстоятельством образа действия, так как на него падает логическое ударение.

Розенталь

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp1474. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

1) **если на первый план выступает значениие обстоятельства образа** действия При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить, 
Точно так же в стихе Гляжу, как безумный, на чёрную шаль (П.) значение **‘подобно безумцу’ преобладает над значением ‘гляжу безумцем’.**

2) если основное значение оборота — **приравнивание** или отождествление: Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей (Л.)

Comment: Интуиция подсказывает мне, что запятая не нужна, но аргументация неубедительна, с рассуждениями про обстоятельство образа действия не согласен.

Comment: Ну а значение подобия, о котором говорится у Розенталя, может быть, подойдет? Но дело даже не в этом. Паузы нет? Нет. Значит, и запятой нет. Мы не можем прочитать предложение  с тремя паузами подряд, мы должны из отдельных фраз построить предложение, а при обособлении это предложение рассыплется на фрагменты. Структуру выбирает автор, и автор через структуру задает значение обороту. Один и тот же оборот в разных предложениях может обособляться или нет. Разве не об этом говорит Розенталь?

Comment: Значение подобия, наоборот, требует запятой (запятая стоит потому, что ‘подобно безумцу’ преобладает над значением ‘гляжу безумцем’). Приравнивания или отождествления тоже нет. Похоже, Розенталь нам не поможет.  "При обособлении это предложение рассыплется на фрагменты" — согласен, но это подсказывает нам, так сказать, здравый смысл, а не правила.

Comment: Правила - это образцы примеров. И у нас по большому счету всё авторское. У автора - выбор подходящей формы для выражения своих мыслей, у а Вас  авторское понимание правил Розенталя (Я уж и не знаю, что важнее). Вот говорит он Вам: подобие можно выразить различным способом, а Вы уверены в обратном. Но давайте сменим тему.  У нас придаточное определительное предложение к какому существительному относится, к одеялу или кокону? Или оно входит в сравнительный оборот?

Comment: Конечно, относится к кокону и входит в  сравнительный оборот. А   в чем подвох? Думаю, в том, что черного цвета макушка к сравнению отношения не имеет.

Comment: Закутался, как в кокон, а макушка уже появились   потом

Comment: Придаточное входит в сравнительный оборот, так как к одеялу относиться не может. Получается такой длинный сравнительный оборот. Читать его, очевидно, надо как единое целое.  А если обособите придаточное, то оно будет относиться к одеялу. Впрочем,  на своем мнении. не настаиваю. Возможно, Вы здесь видите более удачные и правильные ответы.

Comment: И еще последняя заметка: укутался в одеяло с головой - укутался в одеяло как в кокон. В обоих случаях глагол имеет при себе два обстоятельства, причем ударение падает на второе обстоятельство, а на глагол не падает. Это нормальный порядок слов, и это сравнительный оборот в роли этого второго обстоятельства.

Answer (score 4):

"Уткнулся в одеяло" - самодостаточно. Далее следует сравнительный оборот, не имеющий значение обстоятельства образа действия и отделяемый запятой.

***– Свали с радара! Я спать хочу! – зевая, вскрикнул Дмитрий и укутался в одеяло, как в кокон, из которого торчала только черного цвета макушка.***

> Сравнительный оборот, имеющий значение обстоятельства образа действия
>   (отвечает на вопрос как?), не обособляется, так как его можно заменить
>   существительным в творительном падеже или наречием: Как молния
>   пронёсся автомобиль (молнией; молниеносно).

[Обороты с ***как*** выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях:](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/725-29_sravnitelnye_oboroty_i_oboroty_s_kak.html)

> а) если оборот обозначает уподобление (как имеет значение «подобно»,
>   как можно заменить другим сравнительным союзом – *будто, словно, точно*
>   и т.д.).
>
> Ср.: *Её уста, как розы, рдеют* (Пушкин); *Внизу, как зеркало
>   стальное, синеют озера струи* (Тютчев);
>
> б) если в основной части имеется указательное слово *так, такой, тот,
>   столь*:
>
> *Нигде при взаимной встрече не раскланиваются так благородно, как на Невском проспекте* (Гоголь);
>
> в) если оборот начинается сочетанием *как и*:
>
> *К Москве, как и ко всей стране, я чувствую свою сыновность, как к старой няне* (Паустовский);
>
> г) если оборот, являясь приложением, имеет оттенок причинного значения
>   (оборот можно заменить придаточным предложением с союзами *поскольку,
>   так как, потому что* или оборотом с *будучи*):
>
> Ср.: *Как старший, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись*
>   (Куприн). – *Будучи старшим, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно
>   разойтись; Поскольку я являюсь старшим, приказываю вам, господа,
>   немедленно разойтись;*
>
> д) если оборот выражен сочетанием *как правило, как исключение, как
>   всегда, как обычно, как прежде, как сейчас, как нарочно*:
>
> *Вижу, как теперь, самого хозяина* (Пушкин); *Экая досада! Как нарочно, ни души!* (Гоголь).
>
> Но такие обороты не выделяются запятыми, если входят в состав
>   сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу (нет интонации
>   обособления):
>
> *Вчерашний день прошёл как обычно; Всё шло как всегда;*
>
> е) если оборот представляет собой сочетания *не кто иной, как; не что
>   иное, как; не кто другой, как; не что другое, как*:
>
> *Спереди Рейнский водопад не что иное, как невысокий водяной уступ* (Жуковский).

Answer (score 1):

Не входит. Содержание исчерпывается  фразой "уткнулся в одеяло". Сравнение не меняет суть действия. Если всё, что после "как", опустить, предложение сохранит тот же смысл.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос оказался **сложным**, как и сама тема.

1) Рассмотрим **решение с обособлением сравнительного оборота.**

– Свали с радара! Я спать хочу! – зевая, вскрикнул Дмитрий и укутался в одеяло, **как в кокон**, из которого торчала только черного цвета макушка.

В его пользу говорит классическая структура **повтора: *в одеяло, как в кокон*.** А мешает обособлению только **придаточное определительное.** Именно из-за него приходится переносить ударение на ***как в кокон***, считая его определяемым существительным.

Сравнить: – Свали с радара! Я спать хочу! – зевая, вскрикнул Дмитрий и укутался в одеяло, **как в кокон.**

2) **В пользу необособленного оборота говорит только интонация,** то есть интонационно оборот не обособляется. Но ведь это **далеко не первый случай,** когда запятые ставятся только на основании грамматического принципа.

**Например,** не делается пауза после союза И при обособлении деепричастного оборота в ССП,  вводные слова не всегда можно обособить интонационно в сложных конструкциях. Короче говоря, интонационный принцип довольно часто уступает место грамматическому, если они не могут действовать совместно.

**Поэтому приходится выбирать,** и более логично уступить грамматике, так как именно она представлена у нас в письменном виде.